# OpenSSL remains vulnerable to CVE-2016-2107 on 16.04 after applying 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1

Tags: 16.04, openssl

http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2959-1/ lists openssl vulnerability CVE-2016-2107. I applied 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1 and rebooted, but the vulnerability remains. http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-2107.html, states "...OpenSSL before 1.0.1t and 1.0.2 before 1.0.2h does not ... check", which would suggest that 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1 fails to resolve the issue. openssl version -a reports 1 Mar 2016. How to close this vulnerability?

Comment: Please open a bug on Launchpad.

Answer (score -1):

ajr, what confused you is that the package link in the update instructions says libssl1.0.0 but actually links to the openssl package.

(apt install openssl does not work, but installing libssl1.0.0 does resolve the issue)